# how to convert analytic integral into sum

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

I have a composition of functions defined in an integral. For one of the functions, I do not have a functional representation, but have the historical data. Thus, I'd like to use the numerical convolution.

Suppose my outer integral function is defined as follows for a given time horizon $X$ and initial time $x_0$:

$ \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + X} f(x) g(x_0 + X-x) \,dx $

where $f(x) = ln (m(x))$ and $m(x_1) =  m(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_1} h(x) k(x_1 - x) \,dx$.

I have the definition of function $k$, but only have the historical data for function $h$ for each discrete time period. I intend to perform convolution for $h$ and $k$.

$  \int_{x_0}^{x_1} h(x) k(x_1 - x) \,dx \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n} h(i) k(i)$.

I am pretty rusty with my calc skills and am trying to figure out a) whether what I do is correct, and b) how to adjust the indices in the approximate sum presented above. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the primes supposed to indicate in $\ln f(x')$ and $f(x_1')$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, it was a type. It was supposed to be $f^{\prime}(x)$ indicating that it is a different function than $f$.

Comment: Do not use the prime to indicate a different function. All the rest of the world reads this as the derivative of $f$. Use a different letter like $u$. Yes, you are using up half the alphabet. The indices do need to be adjusted. You need $k(n-i)$.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing - though obviously you shouldn't use $g$ or $h$ since they already have a meaning in your post. You could call it $F$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Presumably your data would be a sequence of pairs (where I use $t$ for the $x$-values to avoid confusion with $x_0, x_1$): $\{(t_0, h_0), (t_1, h_1), ...., (t_n, h_n)\}$ where $h_i = h(t_i), t_0 = x_0, t_n = x_1$ and the $t_i$ are in increasing order. The sum you are after is $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}h(x)k(x_1 - x)dx = \sum_{i=1}^n h_ik(x_1 - t_i)(t_i - t_{i-1})$$ Though using the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) instead would give a somewhat better result.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is what I was looking for. How can I apply the trapezoidal rule for the same setting to make a comparison? Also, if you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is of the form $$(t_0, h_0), \dots, (t_n, h_n)$$ with $t_0 = x_0, t_n = x_1$, and $h_i = h(t_i)$ for all $i$, and the $t_i$ are in increasing order, then the trapezoidal rule can be used to estimate the integral. The trapezoidal rule estimates that the average height of the function being integrated on each subinterval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ will be the average of the height at the two endpoints. So the integral is estimated as
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}h(x)k(x_1 - x)\,dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{h_{i-1}k(x_1 - t_{i-1}) + h_ik(x_1 - t_i)}2 (t_i - t_{i-1})$$

If $x_1$ is not one of the known $t_i$, you can interpolate the value of $h(x_1)$ from the surrounding known values: if $t_{k-1} < x_1 < t_k$, then set $t_k^* = x_1$ and $$h_k^* = h(t_k^*) \approx h_{k-1} + \dfrac{x_1 - t_{k-1}}{t_k - t_{k-1}}(h_k - h_{k-1})$$
And use $n = k$ with $(t_k^*, h_k^*)$ replacing $(t_k, h_k)$ in the trapezoidal summation. Similarly for when $x_0$ is not one of the $t_i$.